# What set does this brick come in?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

This brick is part of a 1980-1990's set.
Does anyone know which one?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's [Slope 45 2 x 2 with 3 Gauges and 3 Knobs Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3039px6) and was available in [23 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3039px6&colorID=11&in=A).

[image]